# PHP подключение к удаленной БД

Tags: php, mysql

нужно через php подключиться к удаленной БД (mysql),

При попытке подключиться, выдает ошибку:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:553) in Z:\home\q\www\index.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: OK packet 1 bytes shorter than expected in Z:\home\q\www\index.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2000): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in Z:\home\q\www\index.php on line 3
```

Я так понимаю нужно открыть доступ для моего IP?

Где это и каким образом делается?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по ошибке, дело не в доступе, а в пароле в MySQL-базе. Для вашей учетной записи в базе указан хеш в [старом формате](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html#idm139735111636720), а расширение mysqlnd, которое стало использоваться начиная с PHP 5.3 не использует такие хеши.

Для решения вашей проблемы необходимо задать пароль для вашей учетной записи в новом формате. Для этого в консоли MySQL-сервера выполните:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR `ваша_учетная_запись` = PASSWORD("ваш_текущий_пароль");
```

Или обратитесь к администратору этого сервера.